# Sending email code through asp.net. Not able to resolve the error

Tags: asp.net, smtp, smtpclient

I am using this code for sending email from gmail from iis server deployed app.
I keep getting the message of Failure to connect to remote server.

Please help in resolving this--

```
    protected void SendMail()
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            msg.Subject = "download complete";
            msg.Body = "download is completed";
            msg.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
            msg.To.Add("yyy@gmail.com");
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            System.Net.NetworkCredential basicauthenticationinfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
            client.Port = int.Parse("587");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = basicauthenticationinfo;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should able to [telnet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491013.aspx) the `hostname`(smtp.gmail.com) at that port(587).
If you are able to do so only then you can send mail from your application.

Start your command prompt and check the above command

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

if you get error like this `Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 58
7: Connect failed`

It means that you are not able to connect to the host server. And so you can't send mail using that smtp.